# How do I debug arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I have this assignment that I am having trouble on. I'm supposed to fix syntax error in the code to produce the desired number. I fixed the amount of arrays from 4 to 3 and added "[]" to the end of array in the for loop. I don't know what else there is to fix. Can anyone help?

```
//
// Fix the compiler errors.  The program should display the value 6.
//
package debug5;

public class debug5 {

    public static void rain(String[] args) {}
        int val = 0;  // initialize val to 0.
        int array[] = new int[3];  // create an array of 3 integers.
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;

        // add up the values in the array.
        for (int zx = 0;zx < array.length;zx++)
        }
            val += array;
        {

        system.out.println(val);
    }

}
```

My version :

```
//
// Fix the compiler errors.  The program should display the value 6.
//

package debug5;

public class debug5 {

    public static void rain(String[] args) {}
        int val = 0;  // initialize val to 0.
        int array[] = new int[3];  // create an array of 3 integers.
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;

        // add up the values in the array.
        for (int zx = 0;zx < array.length;zx++)
        }
            val += array[];
        {
        
        system.out.println(val);
    }

}
```

Comment: The `[]` need a value between them. Also, look closer at the braces. Also, look closer at the print command.

Comment: Is there something else wrong? Are there compiler errors? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), and an [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Tangential, but don't blockquote the code--just format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Rafael's answer, be careful with braces and where you'd like to system out.

```
  public static void rain(String[] args) {
  int val = 0;  // initialize val to 0.
  int[] array = new int[3];   // create an array of 3 integers.
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;

    //add up the values in the array.
    for(int zx = 0;zx < array.length ;zx++){
        val += array[zx];
        }


        System.out.println(val);
       }
```

Above code will increment val with each value inside the array and sum inside val variable. Print is done afterwards.

There were some issues with your array initialization and use of arrays and indexes. I suggest you read a bit more on this because this is important on programming

Finally, a better name for the index variable would be i or index instead of zx.

Comment: (Actually this also won't compile)

Comment: you were right. Just fixed it @DaveNewton

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll make sure to use easier index variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
val += array[zx];
```

You have to use the index of the array.